# Maven Build Test Results Just Pass or Fail

Tags: spring, maven, junit, spring-boot

When building using Maven I see a ton of log information being spewed out when running my Junit Tests. I am using spring boot so I see all of the initial log stuff running and would like to see individual test breakdowns to see what number passed, failed or errored out. Is there a plugin that allows this? I've seen it before but can't figure out what to do in my pom to fix it.

Below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>XXXXX</groupId>
<artifactId>XXXXX</artifactId>
<version>0.1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>XXXX</name>
<description>XXXXX</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <jackson.version>2.7.0</jackson.version>
    <netflix.hystrix>1.5.1</netflix.hystrix>
    <netflix.servo>0.12.3</netflix.servo>
    <mockito.version>1.10.18</mockito.version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.8.8</org.aspectj-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
        <artifactId>hystrix-core</artifactId>
        <version>${netflix.hystrix}</version>
        <scope />
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
        <artifactId>hystrix-metrics-event-stream</artifactId>
        <version>${netflix.hystrix}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.servo</groupId>
        <artifactId>servo-core</artifactId>
        <version>${netflix.servo}</version>
        <!--servo's ver of guava conflicts with swagger, exclude it -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
        <artifactId>eureka-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.155</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.archaius</groupId>
        <artifactId>archaius-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.servo</groupId>
        <artifactId>servo-graphite</artifactId>
        <version>${netflix.servo}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.servo</groupId>
        <artifactId>servo-aws</artifactId>
        <version>${netflix.servo}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <!-- This will generate surefire reports for the project -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>

            </configuration>
            <!-- 
            This should prevent surefire from rerunning tests but
            but no failsafe reports are generated
             -->
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>report-only</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: you want to have plugin that gives you an report of junit test cases right?

Comment: Yeah, essentially.

Like:

com.blah.test.Foos
1 Pass, 2 Failed, 3 Errors
com.blah.test2.Bars
3 Pass, 0 Failed, 0 Errors

Comment: @JoelHolmes but you normally already get such report with Maven, what is the parent pom of your project? probably some default behaviors are disabled

Comment: I'm using spring-boot as the parent pom. I'm seeing much more than I want to in terms of logging output during the tests. I would rather see none and just the number of pass or fail

Comment: We can't help if you don't show us your configuration.

Comment: Isn't there a directory storing the unit test result under something like `target/surefire-reports`? Just a simple grep will give you the result you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out all I needed to do was to tell the surefire-plugin to redirect the output:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
       <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us your configuration so we can just guess how to help you.
Most common way to turn off unrelated logging is to configure logging levels in `appliation.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.springframework=WARN
logging.level.org.hibernate=WARN
```

Here is [relevant part of Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-logging).

**If you have Spring packages configured on debug level, Spring Boot run creates huge amount of debug statements. So setting Spring to log level WARN (as sketched above) should filter out most of the log output.**

Comment: There still seems to be a lot of data being dumped with these parameters set. Are these picked up during the maven test cycle?